# Tumblr custom subdomain stoped working

Tags: subdomain, cname, tumblr

I have added my custom `.tk` subdomain to Tumblr. 
My DNS setup for this domain looks like this:

```
A   - mydomain.tk  -   xx.xxx.xxx.xxx ;   
MX  - mydomain.tk  -   xxxxxx.pamx1.hotmail.com ;        
CNAME - blog.mydomain.tk - domains.tumblr.com
```

It was working fine for a month or more, and then all of the sudden I get this error:

> This subdomain's CNAME is not pointing to Tumblr. It is currently set
>   to “DOMAINS.TUMBLR.COM”.

Obviously my domain is set correctly. This error doesn't make sense that the domain is not pointing to `DOMAINS.TUMBLR.COM` when it is pointing to `DOMAINS.TUMBLR.COM`.

When I open my adress `blog.mydomain.tk`, it opens the Tumblr site and shows an error: "There's nothing here." So obviously the problem has to be on their side, right? I wrote to their support about this and first time they fixed it immediately, and then after a couple of hours it happened again, without me even doing anything and now even their support doesn't answer me.

Answer (score 2):

The `CNAME` looks correct according to Tumblr's support doc on [using a custom domain name](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains), and if you're reaching a page on their end (as seen before), it's resolving to their servers.

The problem might be related to the [.tk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tk) ccLTD: Since its registrations are offered [free of charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tk#Overview), spam and phishing operators have historically abused `.tk` domains - see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tk#Abuse) and [this](http://www.zdnet.com/pacific-atoll-a-phishing-haven-1339313909/) for more on that. So it might be triggering Tumblr's filters.

There are also significant restrictions placed on using `.tk` domains by the registry, as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tk):

> There are content restrictions for free domains, banning sites
>   containing sexual content, drug use, hate speech, firearms, and spam
>   or copyright infringement. Also if a domain's redirect target does
>   not work (even temporarily) the domain is taken offline. If a domain
>   violates any of these terms, it is replaced by a Sedo ad page, and no
>   beforehand warning is given. Expired pages (except for those that
>   received complaints of content violations) can be reclaimed by
>   contacting their support system.

Noting the second sentence above, the registry could also take the domain offline if a redirect doesn't work "even temporarily".

So although the problem may lie on Tumblr's end, you might consider obtaining a [generic top level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) (gTLD), which are not very expensive at some registrars. They would have fewer restrictions with more widely accepted recognition.